# trying to change background colour for specific letters

Tags: javascript, html

I want the javascript code to highlight the background colour for all 'a' and 'i' letters in the following two paragraph tags.

I also want the image tag to show correctly. I wasn't linking to an image file in this test so showing correctly just means showing the default image.

At one point i had this code working as expected but then when i tried it later it was no longer working. The only conclusion is i must have changed something but i don't know what.

Can anyone tell me why it doesn't work?

```js
document.querySelectorAll('p').forEach(function(myFirstItem, index) {

  container = ''
  zeroORone = 0

  myFirstItem.innerHTML.split('').forEach(function(mySecondItem) {


    if (mySecondItem == 'a' & zeroORone == 0) {
      container += '<span class="yellow">' + mySecondItem + '</span>'
    } else if (mySecondItem == 'i' & zeroORone == 0) {
      container += '<span class="orange">' + mySecondItem + '</span>'
    } else if (mySecondItem == '<') {
      zeroORone = 1
      container += mySecondItem
    } else if (mySecondItem == '>') {
      zeroORone = 0
      container += mySecondItem
    } else {
      container += mySecondItem
    }


  })


  myFirstItem.innerHTML = container

})
```

```html
<p>piece of a puzzle</p>

<p>Planet <img src="someImage.png"> Earth</p>
```

Comment: why not using `replace` with a `regex` instead of looping through the text?

Comment: it works.  add CSS style for your classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does work, except you have not added `css` for classes `yellow` and `orange`.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('p').forEach(function(myFirstItem, index) {
  container = ''
  zeroORone = 0

  myFirstItem.innerHTML.split('').forEach(function(mySecondItem) {
    if (mySecondItem == 'a' && zeroORone == 0) {
      container += '<span class="yellow">' + mySecondItem + '</span>'
    } else if (mySecondItem == 'i' && zeroORone == 0) {
      container += '<span class="orange">' + mySecondItem + '</span>'
    } else if (mySecondItem == '<') {
      zeroORone = 1
      container += mySecondItem
    } else if (mySecondItem == '>') {
      zeroORone = 0
      container += mySecondItem
    } else {
      container += mySecondItem
    }
  });

  myFirstItem.innerHTML = container

});
```

```css
.yellow {
    background: yellow;
}
.orange {
    background: orange;
}
```

```html
<p>piece of a puzzle</p>
<p>Planet <img src="someImage.png"> Earth</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

I've made some changes to the HTML: I've wrapped the text in span elements. In the javascript I'm searching for the `a` and the `i` and I'm wrapping them in a `<i>` element. Please take a look:

```js
let spans = document.querySelectorAll('span')
   
spans.forEach(s=>{
  let text = s.innerHTML;
  text  = text.replace(/([ai])/g, (found)=> {
      return `<i class='${found}'>${found}</i>`
    });
  s.innerHTML = text;
})
```

```css
i.a{background:yellow}
i.i{background:orange}
```

```html
<p><span>piece of a puzzle</span></p>

<p><span>Planet</span> <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/pin.png"> <span>Earth</span></p>
```

Comment: hello, thanks for the help. Although useful seeing the way you have coded it i'm still wondering why my code didn't work?